# Best way to extend a SASS class with inner selector (subclass)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

Im styling the following HTML to display messages:

```html
  <div className="message">
    <div className="message_label">
      A message
    </div>
  </div>
```

Using the following SCSS class:

```css
  .message {
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 3px solid lightblue;
    &_label {
      color: #444;
      padding: 5px;
    }
  }
```

Following BEM, I want to create another modificator version for error messages:

```html
  <div className="message--error">
    <div className="message_label">
      This is an error!
    </div>
  </div>
```

This version will just change the previous colors to `red` so I want to extend the previous SCSS class:

```css
  .message {
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 3px solid lightblue;
    &_label {
      color: #444;
      padding: 5px;
    }

    &--error {
      @extend .message;
      border: 3px solid red;
      &_label {
        color: red; // This is not working
      }
    }
  }
```

But the selector `message_label` is not working, since its an inner selector and the `@extend` doesnt affect it, as explained in [SCSS Docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend). Whats the best way to extend a class including inner selector?

You can check the DEMO [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-and-scss-fh36e).

Answer (score 1):

The reason this isn't working is because all [`@extend`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend) does is share some css properties across different classes. So in this case, I would expect it to create a selector like:

```
.message, .message--error {
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 3px solid lightblue;
  }

  .message_label {
    color: #444;
    padding: 5px;
  }

  .message--error {
    border: 3px solid red;
  }

  .message--error_label {
    color: red;
  }
```

You can see at the bottom of the above css how your `color: red` might actually end up in a style sheet.

Finally, please do not format your scss like this. It would be a nightmare to maintain and understand.

**Answer**

My suggestion to answer your question is to just use `.message` and `.message--error` on the same element, similar to how [Bootstrap does things](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/)